# ImageButtons not working - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have this `WelcomeActivity` where I programmed 4 ImageButtons to launch another activities.

This is my code:

```
public class WelcomeScreen extends Activity {

ImageButton completeprofile;
ImageButton gotoportfolio;
ImageButton findfriends;
ImageButton readnews;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_activity);

    completeprofile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.completeprofile);
    gotoportfolio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gotoportfolio);
    findfriends = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.findfriends);
    readnews = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.readnews);

    completeprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, LoginMember.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    gotoportfolio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
    });

    findfriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
    });

    readnews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, RegisterMember.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
    });

}}
```

Problem is, they actually behave like buttons when I click them, but no activity is launched, this is the layout declaration:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/completeprofile"
            android:src="@drawable/completeprofile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:contentDescription="completeprofile" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/gotoportfolio"
            android:src="@drawable/gotoportfolio"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/findfriends"
            android:src="@drawable/findfriends"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/readnews"
            android:src="@drawable/readnews"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening? Maybe the intent launch has some issue?

Any ideas?

thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.multidex" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<!-- <uses-sdk  /> -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="Shairlook"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="Shairlook"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.MemberActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.RegisterMember"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.LoginMember"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.WelcomeScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.YoutubeVid"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.ProfileMember"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.PortfolioMember"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.ForgotPassActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="Shairlook"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kkoci.shairlook.WebActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>
```

Comment: Should I reference something on the called activities?

Comment: Did you declare activities in manifest?

Comment: Sure... It's weird I don't know

Comment: I have tested your code. its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the '@Override' from above each onClick method, they are not needed and this may be causing you an issue.

Comment: Ya there was a warning with @override, still same issue though =(

Comment: @NeoVe Can you post your manifest file please? Your current file has no issues with it and so it must be something wrong with a file that is not displayed here.

Comment: Just a question, can I have two activities (classes) pointing to the same layout (different items on same layout)?

Comment: @NeoVe Multiple activities can use the same layout file but in general, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that anyway.

Comment: Yes, I solved it, the problem was the activity related to the layout in which these buttons are, I posted all the logic into the same activity in now it works. thank you very much! Anyways I deleted the @Override and it's working just fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

@override won't cause problem. It's quite weird if activities are added in manifest and present in same pkg.

1. can you please add debug Log in onClick(), this will narrow down the problem whether problem is really with callback or not.
2. try android:clickable="true"/android:focusable="true"/ android:focusableInTouchMode="true" as additional attributes for ImageButton

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, going to add debug to see what happens

Comment: I'm debugging it but nothing happens, I deleted @override because there was a warning, but still same problem, These buttons call activities programmed and declared on manifest, =/

Comment: Maybe I need to reference something on the activities I'm calling?